# How do I get the index of each record displayed on crystal reports?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, crystal-reports

I'm developing winform application using vb.net. I use crystal report in my application. Now i need to store the index of each record that is displaying in current report into database. Then i create another report which displays the index of all the records. My plan is to read the page number of each record and save them on database. I have a group field in the report. I don't know how to scan one by one record and get appropriate page number. I tried the following code to get the field value but did not work.

```
msgbox(rpt.DataDefinition.FormulaFields("name").Text)
```

It displayed the formula of that field.

I don't know in which order the records fetched using following.

```
msgbox(rpt.rows(0).item(0))
```

Please Help me out....

Comment: `Index?` what exactly you mean by it in Crystal reports?

Answer (score 0):

The way your question reads, it sounds like you're trying to generate an "index" for the order records appear in a report and store that index in a database for use in another report.  I am not clear at all what you're trying to do with the page number.

In any case, I need to make something clear: the *definition* of the report (which you're accessing in your code sample) only represents where data will go when the report is *formatted* - **it is not the actual data itself**.

At the most basic level, Crystal Reports takes data out of a database and formats it nicely for you on pages. Rather than trying to take data out of a database, put it into a report, then try to read that report to put it back in a database to make another report, **why not just do all your data manipulation at the database level itself before going to a report in the first place?**

If you *really* must have that first report, the easiest option you'll have for getting at the formatted data is to export it to excel and access it programmatically through an Excel API - Crystal Reports doesn't have an API for getting at your formatted data (including things like generated page numbers, whatever you're trying to do with them).

Comment: It cannot be done at database level itself. The index can be known after generating the first report itself. If i have 100 records and then it takes many pages in report. When i take the print of entire page and do a record book then i may need an index page which says which record exist on which page. Here i have a group field under that many record will come. SO for each group i can identify in which page number it comes and quickly i can access. So i'm trying to get the page number of each group record from the report and save in database.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to break few basic rules. For example a report should never change the data. The right way is to handle data processing in a stored procedure or command and to call the report in  a separate process. In such way you will be able to control the data change and data visualization separately.

P.S. You probably mean "Identifier" not "Index"